# Get user-specific information plus the manager's name

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a code in C# that takes some user information (displayname, jobtitle and department) and also needs the manager's displayname, but I don't know how to get the displayname inside the Manager object inside the User query. How can I do this?

```csharp
var userorg = await graphClient.Users
.Request()
.Select("AccountEnabled,displayName,Department,JobTitle,Manager")
.Top(999)
.GetAsync();

foreach (var user in userorg)
{

    if (user.AccountEnabled == true)
    {                            
        Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
        Console.WriteLine(user.Department);
        Console.WriteLine(user.JobTitle);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Edit: I created a new solution because the old one was VERY old and very dirty. Using the code as a base, I recreated what I needed and it works well, but it only displays the first 100, even including Top = 999. It only makes a difference if I put the TOP below 100, but above that it is ignored. In the old code, TOP 999 worked.

Edit2: I managed to solve the problem using odata.nextlink, I just don't know if it was the best way, the important thing is that it works!

```csharp
var csv = new StringBuilder();

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "xxxx";
var tenantId = "xxxxx";
var clientSecret = "xxxxxx";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

int i = 0;
string sToken = null;

try
{
    while (i == 0 || sToken != null)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "manager($select=displayName,id)" };
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[]
                { "accountEnabled", "displayName", "UserPrincipalName", "department", "jobTitle", "manager" };
            });

            foreach (var user in users.Value)
            {
                if (user.AccountEnabled == true && user.UserPrincipalName.Contains("crebti.onmicrosoft.com") != true
                    && user.UserPrincipalName.Contains("#EXT") != true)
                {
                    string f = user.DisplayName;
                    string s = user.Department;
                    string t = user.JobTitle;
                    string q = null;
                    if (user.Manager != null)
                    {
                        var manager = await graphClient.Users[user.Manager.Id].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                        {
                            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "displayName" };
                        });
                        q = manager.DisplayName;
                    }
                    var nL = $"{f},{s},{t},{q}";
                    csv.AppendLine(nL);
                }
                
            }
            if (users.OdataNextLink != null)
            {
                sToken = users.OdataNextLink;
                string tokin = "$skiptoken=";
                sToken = sToken.Substring(sToken.IndexOf(tokin) + tokin.Length);
            }
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            string delta = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=manager($select=displayName,id),&$select=accountEnabled,displayName,UserPrincipalName,department,jobTitle,manager,&$skiptoken=" + sToken;
            var result = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Delta.DeltaRequestBuilder(delta, graphClient.RequestAdapter);
            var users = await result.GetAsync();

            foreach (var user in users.Value)
            {
                if (user.AccountEnabled == true && user.UserPrincipalName.Contains("crebti.onmicrosoft.com") != true
                    && user.UserPrincipalName.Contains("#EXT") != true)
                {
                    string f = user.DisplayName;
                    string s = user.Department;
                    string t = user.JobTitle;
                    string q = null;
                    if (user.Manager != null)
                    {
                        var manager = await graphClient.Users[user.Manager.Id].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                        {
                            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "displayName" };
                        });
                        q = manager.DisplayName;
                    }
                    var nL = $"{f},{s},{t},{q}";
                    csv.AppendLine(nL);
                }
            }
            if (users.OdataNextLink != null)
            {
                sToken = users.OdataNextLink;
                string tokin = "$skiptoken=";
                sToken = sToken.Substring(sToken.IndexOf(tokin) + tokin.Length);
                //pipipopopo
            }
            else sToken = null;
        }
        
    }
    File.WriteAllText("Auditoria.csv", csv.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    MessageBox.Show(odataError.Error.Message, odataError.Error.Code);
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You need to use **`$expand`** in your graph query to get **manager** details along with user information.

When I ran below query by including `$expand` in **[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)**,  I got the **response** like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=manager($select=displayName),&$select=displayName,department,jobTitle,manager
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get the **same results** using c#, I ran below code and got user's information along with **manager's name** successfully like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
using System;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "manager($select=displayName,id)" };
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "accountEnabled", "displayName", "department", "jobTitle", "manager" };
    });

    foreach (var user in users.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {user.DisplayName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Job Title: {user.JobTitle}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Department: {user.Department}");
        if (user.Manager != null)
        {
            var manager = await graphClient.Users[user.Manager.Id].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "displayName" };
            });
            Console.WriteLine($"Manager: {manager.DisplayName}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
    }
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I was using a very old version of references, I started a new one from scratch and your code worked, but I can't display more than 100 results even with `requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 999;`. I will edit the question with the current code

Comment: I managed to solve it, I just don't know if it was the best way. I'll include it in the edit if anyone needs it

Comment: From documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-3-use-select-to-retrieve-specific-properties-of-a-user